# Remove slivers and gaps in polgons (PostGIS, R QGIS)

Tags: r, gis, postgis, polygon, qgis

I have a large polygon dataset, with slivers between almost all polygons. I've tried buffering (and negative buffering) to expand each feature, but this results in both slight overlaps and also retains some (smaller) slivers.

Do you have any suggestions for how I could make a topologically clean polygon dataset? It's in PostGIS but I'm happy to work in R or QGIS too.

I was thinking about snapping each vertex to a 5 m grid but really I want to snap the vertices to the line of the adjacent polygon... or buffer more and then delete parts of the polygons that overlap each other.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided no sample data at all, the bast I can come up with is this simple proof-of-concept (in R, using the `snap()`-function from the `terra`-package)

```
#some sample data polygons with a small gap between them
library(terra)
p1 <- as.polygons(ext(0,1,0,1))
p2 <- as.polygons(ext(1.1,2,0,1))
p <- rbind(p1, p2)
plot(p)
```

[image]

```
#snap the polygons together, based on a a threshold distance of 0.15
y <- snap(p, tol=.15)
plot(y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can do this analysis with the cost of precision of the polygon dataset. For this, you can try out the "Snap geometries to layer" tool (Processing Toolbox > QGIS Geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools > Snap geometries to layer. Just set the parameters that your polygon layer is in both reference and input data (for the precision you would need a reference layer, that has correct border lines, but it seems that you can compromise with this..) and then test different tolerance distance with different calculation methods. For simple polygons, the results will be following:
[test data with tool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGTv6.png). [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cXBb.png).

Answer (score 0):

This answer adds to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77844883/15137041 by @ville-hamunen.

In R, you can use package [`{qgisprocess}`](https://r-spatial.github.io/qgisprocess/) to run QGIS processing algorithms (including those from processing plugins). In this case you'd need to run `qgis_run_algorithm("native:snapgeometries", )`, including the arguments (which can be R objects) that the algorithm needs; see `qgis_show_help("native:snapgeometries")`.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS: Use “Delete holes” from the Vector Geometry processing toolbox. As explained in the tool:

> This algorithm takes a polygon layer and removes holes in polygons. It creates a new vector layer in which polygons with holes have been replaced by polygons with only their external ring. Attributes are not modified.

I left the optional minimum area parameter default 0.0; that resulted:

> ...in all holes being removed.

Here's the link to: [QGIS manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#delete-holes/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).